# Entity Framework : Object is null but the foreign key isn't

Tags: c#, model, .net-core, foreign-keys, ef-core-2.1

I'm learning .NET Core and EF Core, but I already have an issue.

I created my code from scratch,

Here's my code :

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Muscle> Muscle { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exercice> Exercice { get; set; }
}
public class Muscle
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Exercice> Exercices { get; set; }
}
public class Exercice
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string libelle { get; set; }

    public int MuscleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Muscle Muscle { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to get my first "Exercice", his "MuscleId" is "1" but his "Muscle" is null...
And if I try to get my first "Muscle", "Exercices" is null aswell ...

[image]

Is there something I have to do to make this work? 
Thanks

Comment: Try using the `Include()` when querying from DbContext . Here is an example from one of my projects: `DifferencesContext db = new DifferencesContext();
            var differences = db.Differences.Include(d => d.Branch).Include(d => d.DifferenceType).Include(d => d.State).ToList()`. Without `Include()` those three properties were always null (Branch, DifferenceType, State) only the keys were returned (BranchId,.. etc.). I think this is the same with EntityFramework and EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 0):

Your Muscle class primary key should match foreign key on Exercise class. Like this.

```
public class Muscle
{
    [Key]
    public int MuscleId { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exercice> Exercices { get; set; }
}
```

Or  use 
    [ForeignKey] Attribute.
You can read more here. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I tried with the [ForeignKey] but no changes... :/ and using the "same name" will not change a thing since my "MuscleId" is not null. Only the "Muscle" is